# При запуске простого кода в Python3 выдает 404 Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```
from flask import Flask
from vsearch import search4letters
app = Flask(__name__)

# Первый декоратор выводит на экран надпись:'
@app.route('/')
def hello() -> str:
    return 'Hello world from Flask'

# Второй декоратор устанавливает URL 'search4'
@app.route('/search4')

# Функция 'do_search' вызывает 'search4letters' и возвращает результат в виде строки
def do_search() -> str:
    return str(search4letters('life, the universe, and everything', 'eiru!'))

app.run()
```

Я запускаю код в командной строке и ввожу в поле поиска браузера 127.0.0.1:5000 на экране появляется первое сообщение "Hello World from Flask!", но когда ввожу 127.0.0.1:5000/search4 этот запрос, появляется вот такое сообщение:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Я занимаюсь с помощью книги <Изучаем программирование с помощью Python Head First>делаю точно также как в книге, но не получается. Создал свой модуль установил этот модуль в папку где хранится вышеуказанная программа.

Comment: Так у вас для `/search4` нет `view` функции. В декоратор `@app.route('/search4')` нужно обернуть функцию, которая должна возвращать ответ по данному `uri`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Подскажите, пож-та, как это сделать?

Comment: Так же как и функцию `hello` вы обернули в декоратор `@app.route('/')`

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону vsearch, подозреваю проблема в нем. Так как если do_search return заменить на простой текст то все будет работать.

Comment: "В декоратор @app.route('/search4') нужно обернуть функцию, которая должна возвращать ответ по данному uri" - подскажите пож-та как это сделать? Я только учусь, не совсем понял. И так и сяк пробовал, ничего не выходит.

Comment: @app.route('/search4') должен быть прямо над def do_search() -> str: без пустых строк и коментариев

Comment: @Jack_oS у меня подобный код работает вместе с пустыми строками и комментариями. Возможно в чем-то другом проблема.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@app.route('/search4')
def show_result():
   return "It's work now"
```

Вот так будет всё работать.